# Change JqGrid Checkbox name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a JqGrid with 3 columns and all 3 of them are checkbox type columns.

In my first column, when check box is checked then a text 'Enabled' will be displayed adjacent to checkbox in the same column cell using Check box formatter function.

Now I need to change this 'Enabled' text to 'Enabled for Edit' when third check box is checked after Grid load.

i.e, After JqGrid loaded,  my first column checkbox text should be updated based on my third column checkbox check/uncheck value using checkbox formatter.

I tried below one, inside checkbox formatter function but this variable always returns false even my third column check box is checked.

```
Var cellvalue = $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getCell',row_id,'3rdColumn');

If(cellvalue == true)
Labetext = "MyText";
Else
Labetext = "OldText";
```

I am not sure, where I made a mistake. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Default value of check box is false.

Comment: @G01, During Grid load my third column checkbox is checked but still this variable returns false.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, *complete*, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please, post your jqGrid code and let us know which version of jqGrid is used?